# Binding DataGridComboBox Column to a List of Values

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am binding a DataGrid to a DataTable;
the DataGrid has 4 columns:

1. CheckBox (no issues)
2. Text Box 1 (no issues)
3. Text Box 2 (no issues)
4. Combobox (Here is where I am facing the problem)

Currently as I am binding my DataGrid to a Datatable, I am assigning default values to the DataGridComboBox Column.
My questions might be very basic (new to WPF).
But I am not able to get the "drop down" style and how to choose the options?
How do I bind the values of DataGridComboBox: ItemSource to an array maybe? while keeping the value bound in a datatable?

Here is the part of the code used:

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ControlOption" Header ="ControlOption" Width="100"
        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Operation}
        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=DataGridComboxBox_Control}"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        CanUserResize="True">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                 <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
                 <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Choices}" />
             </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

CodeBehind:

```
_ds = new DataSet();
          DataTable table = new DataTable();
          _ds.Tables.Add(table);
          DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("IsActive", typeof(bool));
          table.Columns.Add(c1);
          DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("DataGridTextBox1", typeof(string));
          table.Columns.Add(c2);
          DataColumn c3 = new DataColumn("DataGridTextBox_Summary", typeof(string));
          table.Columns.Add(c3);
          DataColumn c4 = new DataColumn("DataGridComboxBox_Control", typeof(string));
          table.Columns.Add(c4);

datagrid.ItemsSource = _ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

I want to bind the DataGridComboxBox_Control to a list of choices {"A","B","C"}
Please let me know how to go about it. I have tried a few solutions, but did not work for me